# How to change \bibliographystyle to IEEEtran in Tufte template

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, tufte-book

In the Tufte template, how do you go about changing the bibliography to the IEEEtran format?  I tried `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, but I get an error being thrown:

`! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.`

Here is the Tufte template

**CODE**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Tufte-Style Book (Documentation Template)
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (5/1/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% The Tufte-LaTeX Developers (tufte-latex.googlecode.com)
%
% License:
% Apache License (Version 2.0)
%
% IMPORTANT NOTE:
% In addition to running BibTeX to compile the reference list from the .bib
% file, you will need to run MakeIndex to compile the index at the end of the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\hypersetup{colorlinks} % Comment this line if you don't wish to have colored links

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage{booktabs} % Better horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed to insert images into the document
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % Sets the default location of pictures
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} % Improves figure scaling

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize} % The font size of all verbatim text can be changed here

\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}} % New command to create parentheses around text in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}} % New command to create asterisks in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing

\usepackage{xspace} % Used for printing a trailing space better than using a tilde (~) using the \xspace command

\newcommand{\monthyear}{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space\number\year} % A command to print the current month and year

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{ % This block sets up a command for printing an epigraph with 2 arguments - the quote and the author
\begin{fullwidth}
\sffamily\large
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\allcaps{#1}\\ % The quote
\noindent\allcaps{#2} % The author
\end{doublespace}
\end{fullwidth}
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage} % Command to insert a blank page

\usepackage{units} % Used for printing standard units

\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}} % Print text in maroon
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}} % Used for printing commands in the index, moves the slash left so the command name aligns with the rest of the text in the index
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}} % Command to print a very short space
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace} % Command to print i.e.
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace} % Command to print e.g.
\newcommand{\na}{\quad--} % Used in tables for N/A cells
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}} % Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of: 10/12x26 pc.
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}} % Command to print a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1

\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}
\newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}} % Command to print the XeLaTeX logo while simultaneously adding the position to the index

\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}} % Command to print a command in texttt with a backslash of tt type without inserting the command into the index

\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{\hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}} % Command to define a command in red and add it to the index
{ % If no package is specified, add the command to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{ % If a package is also specified as a second argument, add the command and package to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{% Command to define a command and add it to the index
\texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}% If no package is specified, add the command to the index
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

% A bunch of new commands to print commands, arguments, environments, classes, etc within the text using the correct formatting
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces}{\end{quotation}}
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Used to generate the index
\makeindex % Generate the index which is printed at the end of the document

% This block contains a number of shortcuts used throughout the book
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BOOK META-INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{A Tufte-Style Book\thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}} % Title of the book

\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers} % Author

\publisher{Publisher of This Book} % Publisher



\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EPIGRAPH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
\openepigraph{The public is more familiar with bad design than good design. It is, in effect, conditioned to prefer bad design, because that is what it lives with. The new becomes threatening, the old reassuring.}{Paul Rand, {\itshape Design, Form, and Chaos}}
\vfill
\openepigraph{A designer knows that he has achieved perfection not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.}{Antoine de Saint-Exup\'{e}ry}
\vfill
\openepigraph{\ldots the designer of a new system must not only be the implementor and the first large-scale user; the designer should also write the first user manual\ldots If I had not participated fully in all these activities, literally hundreds of improvements would never have been made, because I would never have thought of them or perceived why they were important.}{Donald E. Knuth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\maketitle % Print the title page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
Copyright \copyright\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor

\par\smallcaps{Published by \thanklesspublisher}

\par\smallcaps{tufte-latex.googlecode.com}

\par Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the ``License''); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \smallcaps{``AS IS'' BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\index{license}

\par\textit{First printing, \monthyear}
\end{fullwidth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\listoffigures % Print a list of figures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\listoftables % Print a list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
~\vfill
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont\itshape
\nohyphenation
Dedicated to those who appreciate \LaTeX{} and the work of \mbox{Edward R.~Tufte} and \mbox{Donald E.~Knuth}.
\end{doublespace}
\vfill
\vfill

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction} % The asterisk leaves out this chapter from the table of contents

This sample book discusses the design of Edward Tufte's books\cite{Tufte2001,Tufte1990,Tufte1997,Tufte2006} and the use of the \doccls{tufte-book} and \doccls{tufte-handout} document classes.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{The Design of Tufte's Books}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\newthought{The pages} of a book are usually divided into three major sections: the front matter (also called preliminary matter or prelim), the main matter (the core text of the book), and the back matter (or end matter).

\newthought{The front matter} of a book refers to all of the material that comes before the main text. The following table shows a list of material that appears in the front matter of \VDQI, \EI, \VE, and \BE along with its page number. Page numbers that appear in parentheses refer to folios that do not have a printed page number (but they are still counted in the page number sequence).

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Books} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
Page content & \vdqi & \ei & \ve & \be \\
\midrule
Blank half title page & \hangp{1} & \hangp{1} & \hangp{1} & \hangp{1} \\
Frontispiece\footnotemark{}
& \hangp{2} & \hangp{2} & \hangp{2} & \hangp{2} \\
Full title page & \hangp{3} & \hangp{3} & \hangp{3} & \hangp{3} \\
Copyright page & \hangp{4} & \hangp{4} & \hangp{4} & \hangp{4} \\
Contents & \hangp{5} & \hangp{5} & \hangp{5} & \hangp{5} \\
Dedication & \hangp{6} & \hangp{7} & \hangp{7} & 7 \\
Epigraph & -- & -- & \hangp{8} & -- \\
Introduction & \hangp{7} & \hangp{9} & \hangp{9} & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-7\baselineskip}\footnotetext{The contents of this page vary from book to book. In \vdqi this page is blank; in \ei and \ve this page holds a frontispiece; and in \be this page contains three epigraphs.}
\vspace{7\baselineskip}

\bigskip
The design of the front matter in Tufte's books varies slightly from the traditional design of front matter. First, the pages in front matter are traditionally numbered with lowercase roman numerals (\eg, i, ii, iii, iv,~\ldots). Second, the front matter page numbering sequence is usually separate from the main matter page numbering. That is, the page numbers restart at 1 when the main matter begins. In contrast, Tufte has enumerated his pages with arabic numerals that share the same page counting sequence as the main matter.

There are also some variations in design across Tufte's four books. The page opposite the full title page (labeled ``frontispiece'' in the above table) has different content in each of the books. In \VDQI, this page is blank; in \EI and \VE, this page holds a frontispiece; and in \BE, this page contains three epigraphs.

The dedication appears on page~6 in \vdqi (opposite the introduction), and is placed on its own spread in the other books. In \ve, an epigraph shares the spread with the opening page of the introduction.

None of the page numbers (folios) of the front matter are expressed except in \be, where the folios start to appear on the dedication page.

\newthought{The full title page} of each of the books varies slightly in design. In all the books, the author's name appears at the top of the page, the title it set just above the center line, and the publisher is printed along the bottom margin. Some of the differences are outlined in the following table.

\bigskip
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
Feature & \vdqi & \ei & \ve & \be \\
\midrule
Author & & & & \\
\quad Typeface & serif & serif & serif & sans serif \\
\quad Style & italics & italics & italics & upright, caps \\
\quad Size & 24 pt & 20 pt & 20 pt & 20 pt \\
\addlinespace
Title & & & & \\
\quad Typeface & serif & serif & serif & sans serif \\
\quad Style & upright & italics & upright & upright, caps \\
\quad Size & 36 pt & 48 pt & 48 pt & 36 pt \\
\addlinespace
Subtitle & & & & \\
\quad Typeface & \na & \na & serif & \na \\
\quad Style & \na & \na & upright & \na \\
\quad Size & \na & \na & 20 pt & \na \\
\addlinespace
Edition & & & & \\
\quad Typeface & sans serif & \na & \na & \na \\
\quad Style & upright, caps & \na & \na & \na \\
\quad Size & 14 pt & \na & \na & \na \\
\addlinespace
Publisher & & & & \\
\quad Typeface & serif & serif & serif & sans serif \\
\quad Style & italics & italics & italics & upright, caps \\
\quad Size & 14 pt & 14 pt & 14 pt & 14 pt \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{figure*}[p]
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/vdqi-title.pdf}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/ei-title.pdf}}
\\\vspace{\baselineskip}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/ve-title.pdf}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/be-title.pdf}}
\end{figure*}

\newthought{The tables of contents} in Tufte's books give us our first glimpse of the structure of the main matter. \VDQI is split into two parts, each containing some number of chapters. His other three books only contain chapters---they're not broken into parts.

\begin{figure*}[p]\index{table of contents}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/vdqi-contents.pdf}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/ei-contents.pdf}}
\\\vspace{\baselineskip}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/ve-contents.pdf}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/be-contents.pdf}}
\end{figure*}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Typefaces}\label{sec:typefaces1}\index{typefaces}
\index{fonts|see{typefaces}}

Tufte's books primarily use two typefaces: Bembo and Gill Sans. Bembo is used for the headings and body text, while Gill Sans is used for the title page and opening epigraphs in \BE.

Since neither Bembo nor Gill Sans are available in default \LaTeX{} installations, the \TL document classes default to using Palatino and Helvetica, respectively. In addition, the Bera Mono typeface is used for \texttt{monospaced} type.

The following font sizes are defined by the \TL classes:

\begin{table}[h]\index{typefaces!sizes}
\footnotesize%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccl}
\toprule
\LaTeX{} size & Font size & Leading & Used for \\
\midrule
\verb+\tiny+ & 5 & 6 & sidenote numbers \\
\verb+\scriptsize+ & 7 & 8 & \na \\
\verb+\footnotesize+ & 8 & 10 & sidenotes, captions \\
\verb+\small+ & 9 & 12 & quote, quotation, and verse environments \\
\verb+\normalsize+ & 10 & 14 & body text \\
\verb+\large+ & 11 & 15 & \textsc{b}-heads \\
\verb+\Large+ & 12 & 16 & \textsc{a}-heads, \textsc{toc} entries, author, date \\
\verb+\LARGE+ & 14 & 18 & handout title \\
\verb+\huge+ & 20 & 30 & chapter heads \\
\verb+\Huge+ & 24 & 36 & part titles \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{A list of \LaTeX{} font sizes as defined by the \TL document classes.}
\label{tab:font-sizes}
\end{table}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Headings}\label{sec:headings1}\index{headings}

Tufte's books include the following heading levels: parts, chapters,\sidenote{Parts and chapters are defined for the \texttt{tufte-book} class only.} sections, subsections, and paragraphs. Not defined by default are: sub-subsections and subparagraphs.

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
\toprule
Heading & Style & Size \\
\midrule
Part & roman & \measure{24}{36}{40} \\
Chapter & italic & \measure{20}{30}{40} \\
Section & italic & \measure{12}{16}{26} \\
Subsection & italic & \measure{11}{15}{26} \\
Paragraph & italic & 10/14 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Heading styles used in \BE.}
\label{tab:heading-styles}
\end{table}

\paragraph{Paragraph} Paragraph headings (as shown here) are introduced by italicized text and separated from the main paragraph by a bit of space.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Environments}

The following characteristics define the various environments:

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
Environment & Font size & Notes \\
\midrule
Body text & \measure{10}{14}{26} & \\
Block quote & \measure{9}{12}{24} & Block indent (left and right) by \unit[1]{pc} \\
Sidenotes & \measure{8}{10}{12} & Sidenote number is set inline, followed by word space \\
Captions & \measure{8}{10}{12} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Environment styles used in \BE.}
\label{tab:environment-styles}
\end{table}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\backmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliography{References/bibliography} % Use the bibliography.bib file for the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % Use the plainnat style of referencing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printindex % Print the index at the very end of the document

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load the `natbib` package and keep using `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`. Alternatively, stop loading the `biblatex` package, delete all aux files, and start over with the `natbib` citation management package and the `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for your input.  How to not load the natbib package?

Comment: I tried the comment `\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=false,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}` but I still get the error of Incompatible package 'natbib'.